# Struts 2 how to specify configuration file location outside class path

Tags: configuration, struts2, struts

I am trying set a init-param for struts 2 filter like this:

```xml
<init-param>
    <param-name>config</param-name>
    <param-value>struts-default.xml,struts-plugin.xml,/WEB-INF/etc/struts.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
```

but it does't work. Can't we put struts 2 configuration file outside class path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't, but you can specify a relative path

```xml
<param-value>struts-default.xml,struts-plugin.xml,../etc/struts.xml</param-value>
```

Comment: I haven't tested that, does it work? That seems weird to me, since WEB-INF is definitely off the classpath. I'll have to try it.

Comment: yes, it works, but I've updated the path, because `../` points to `WEB-INF`.

Comment: I have tested this with struts 2.3.15, it works! thank you @RomanC